# SharePoint 2013 Performance Testing

Tags: performance, word, office, testing

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 to create a number of web performance tests for a customer.
One of the tests they would like to perform is the opening of documents within the Microsoft Office Client apps. Clicking 'Edit' on a document obviously fires up Word but as this is outside of the browser there doesn't appear to be a way to monitor how long this process takes.

Can anyone shed any light on to how this could be captured?